# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined with Kriskowal's q (Q.defer.resolve)

Tags: javascript, q

I am trying the promise library q by Kriskowal. Why do I get this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
var d = Q.defer();
d.promise.then(function(){console.log("finished")});
d.resolve(true); // "finished"; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

In addition I wonder why I have to resolve the deferred object with true in order to resolve it. I am used to angular's implementation $q where you could just resolve without any argument.

Comment: It looks like it works actually (http://jsfiddle.net/p51ygdr9/), maybe there is a problem with the import ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the q.js from the official github repository. By using version 0.9.6 from cdnjs, like in your jsfiddle, I get another error. I am including only the file with the <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>.

` 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'promiseDispatch' of undefined (isPromise @ q.js:839)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm that's strange. Did you use exactly the same code as given ?
Did you get the same error with the latest version ?
One option could be to check if you haven't override a native javascript function like ```window.theNativeFunction = function(){};```

Comment: Oops! I overwrote the Object class! Thanks a lot for your help!